# Parse data from Excel to IE using VBA

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, vba

I am trying to parse some data from an Excel sheet to an IE page using VBA and I have difficulties in sending data to one object that look like a special combobox.

In fact there are 2 comboboxes on that particular page define as following:

#### Combobox 1:

```
<selectname="material[]">
<optionvalue="3">AL</option>
<optionvalue="2">TL</option>
<optionvalue="1">GL</option>
```

#### Combobox 2:

```
<divclass="ui-widget">
<selectname="partner" id="ID" style="width:300px">
<optionvalue="no"></option>
<optionvalue="3766">COMPANY 1</option>
<optionvalue="3792">COMPANY2</option>
<optionvalue="3764">COMPANY 3</option>
<optionvalue="3071">COMPANY 4</option>
```

While I can send the data to combobox 1 using the following code:

```
IE.document.all.Item("material[]").selectedIndex = "2"
```

it seems that the same code doesn't function on the second combobox:

```
IE.document.all.Item("partner").selectedIndex = "3766"
```

and no data is displayed (nor trigger any errors).

Do you have any ideas how could I accomplish this?

Comment: What does Java have to do with this?  BTW Java!=JavaScript

Comment: BTW - `optionvalue` should be `option value`.  GI/GO. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing the **value** of a `select` with it's **index**.  The two things are unrelated.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your feedback. I am aware of the difference between these two, my question was basically how can I set the index to the second combobox.

Comment: You loop through the options until you find the value you're looking for, then set selectedIndex to x where x is the zero-based index of that option.